# C programming, need help getting user input into a for loop

Tags: c

So this C program displays a menu and asks the user to input a number from 1-4. If one is selected, the program then asks the user to input the parameters. Then the menu is displayed again. If 2 is chosen, the program should display the user's inputs in a formatted table. That is where I am having trouble, I do not know how to get the user inputs into a for loop to print it out in a formatted table. Here is the code i currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int numOfInst, totalCycles, totalInst, clockRate;

void parameters(){
totalInst = 0;
totalCycles = 0;
int counter, cpiClass, instCount;

printf("Enter the number of instruction classes: \n");
scanf(" %d", &numOfInst);
printf("Enter the frequency of the machine (MHz): \n");
scanf(" %d", &clockRate);

for (counter = 0; counter < numOfInst; counter++){
    printf("Enter CPI of class %d: ", counter + 1);
    scanf(" %d", &cpiClass);
    printf("Enter instruction count of class %d (millions): ", counter + 1);
    scanf(" %d", &instCount);

    totalInst += instCount;
    totalCycles += cpiClass * instCount;
}
    return;

} 

float avgCPI(){
float avg = totalCycles / ((float)totalInst);
return (avg);
}

float execTime(){
float time = (totalCycles / ((float)clockRate)) * 1000;
return (time);
}

float calcMips(){
float mips = totalInst / (totalCycles / ((float)clockRate));
return (mips);

}
void printParam(){
int i;
printf("-------------------------\n");
printf("| Class\t | CPI\t |Count\t |\n");
for (i  = 0; i < numOfInst; i++);
printf(" %d\t", (i));
/*totalCycles[i], totalInst[i]);*/
return;
}

/*void printPerformance{
}*/
int main()
{
int option;
do {
    printf("Performance assessment: ");
    printf("\n-----------------------");
    printf("\n1) Enter parameters: ");
    printf("\n2) Print table of parameters: ");
    printf("\n3) Print table of performance ");
    printf("\n4) Quit \n");
    scanf(" %d", &option);

    switch (option){
    case 1: parameters();
        break;
    case 2: printParam();
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    default: printf("Invalid input, please enter a number from 1-4 ");


    }


}while(option != 4);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you could explore *arrays*. Your code is ok when summing the input data, but does not remember each value entered for printing. You have a hint of them in the commented-out `/*totalCycles[i], totalInst[i]);*/`

Comment: you have to use array here. If you give hints what's  data you want to print then I can solve it.

Comment: Enter selection: 1

Enter the number of instruction classes: 3
Enter the frequency of the machine (MHz): 200
Enter CPI of class 1: 2
Enter instruction count of class 1 (millions): 3
Enter CPI of class 2: 4
Enter instruction count of class 2 (millions): 5
Enter CPI of class 3: 6
Enter instruction count of class 3 (millions): 7

Comment: After that it supposed to print the user inputs as follows -------------------------
|Class  |CPI    |Count  |
-------------------------
|1      |2      |3      |
-------------------------
|2      |4      |5      |
-------------------------
|3      |6      |7      |
-------------------------
@FarhadurRajaFahim

Comment: @doctrshoe i have solve your problem. Hope you will understand :) If you have any query let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int cpiClass[10000], instCount[10000], numOfInst;
void parameters(){
    int counter;
    printf("Enter the number of instruction classes: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &numOfInst);
    for (counter = 0; counter < numOfInst; counter++){
        printf("Enter CPI of class %d: ", counter + 1);
        scanf(" %d", &cpiClass[counter]);
        printf("Enter instruction count of class %d (millions): ", counter + 1);
        scanf(" %d", &instCount[counter]);
   }
   return;
}
void printParam(){
    int i;
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("| Class\t | CPI\t |Count\t |\n");
    for (i  = 0; i < numOfInst; i++){
        printf(" %d\t%d\t%d\t\n", i+1,cpiClass[i],instCount[i]);
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int option;
    do {
        printf("\nPerformance assessment: ");
        printf("\n-----------------------");
        printf("\n1) Enter parameters: ");
        printf("\n2) Print table of parameters: ");
        printf("\n3) Quit \n");
        scanf(" %d", &option);
        switch (option){
        case 1: parameters();
            break;
        case 2: printParam();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default: printf("Invalid input, please enter a number from 1-3 ");
       }
    }while(option != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine as your accepted output.

**What i edit here:**

In line 5 i declare 2 array and make them public.

```
int cpiClass[1000], instCount[10000], numOfInst;
```

In **parameters()** function line 12 and 14 take input in array.

```
scanf(" %d", &cpiClass[counter]);
scanf(" %d", &instCount[counter]);
```

Now all my input data store in those 2 array.

In main function when choose option 2 it shows data from those array.

In **printParam()** function edit

```
printf(" %d\t%d\t%d\t\n", i+1,cpiClass[i],instCount[i]);
```

This print function will show your output as you accepted.

> **Note:**

Here some function are missing if you compare with your code. I have remove them because those are not needed for showing this output.

> If you need all code then go [here](https://ideone.com/zb4tIN).

I have put all code there including other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how you only have int variables to store numOfInst, totalCycles, totalInst, and clockRate. This means that whenever you assign a value to these variables, the previous value is overwritten and lost. In order to print out all previous inputs, you must store them in some data structure (hint: take a look at lists or hashmaps). Using arrays to store the inputs would also work, but this limits the number of inputs you can store to the size of the array.